# Burger Menu should close after click

Tags: javascript, navigation

i'm trying to create a Burger Menu, open it's displayed full-size. But when I click on one of the links, the revealed burger menu is still visible. How do i make it dissapear automatically?

This is the script I'm using:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
$('#slide-in-open').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('.slide-in-menu-container').toggleClass('slide-in-menu');
});
    });
</script>
```

```
#slide-in-open{
cursor: pointer;
}
 
.line{
display: block;
position: absolute;
right:10px;
height: 3px;
width: 30px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 9px;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .1s ease-in-out;
transition: .1s ease-in-out;
}
 
.line-2 {
top: 8px;
}
 
.line-3 {
top: 16px;
}
 
#slide-in-open.open .line-1 {
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
-o-transform: rotate(135deg);
transform: rotate(135deg);
}
 
#slide-in-open.open .line-2 {
display: none;
}
 
#slide-in-open.open .line-3 {
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
 
.slide-in-menu {
right: 0 !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
}
 
.slide-in-menu-container {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}





<header class="et-l et-l--header">
            <div class="et_builder_inner_content et_pb_gutters3">
        <div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0_tb_header et_pb_sticky_module et_section_regular" style="">
                
                
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0_tb_header et_pb_gutters2 et_pb_row_6col">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_0_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p>Leistungen</p></div>
            </div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_1_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_1_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p>Sortiment</p></div>
            </div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_2_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et_pb_column_empty">
                
                
                
                
                
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_3_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et_pb_column_empty">
                
                
                
                
                
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_4_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_2_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p>Einblicke</p></div>
            </div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_6 et_pb_column_5_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_3_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p>Kontakt</p></div>
            </div>
            </div>
                
                
                
                
            </div><div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_1_tb_header">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_6_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_0_tb_header">
                
                
                
                
                <a href="/#top"><span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img decoding="async" src="https://diebrillenboutique.de/wp-content/uploads/Gruppe-52.svg" alt="" title="Gruppe 52" class="wp-image-518"></span></a>
            </div>
            </div>
                
                
                
                
            </div>
                
                
            </div><div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_1_tb_header slide-in-menu et_pb_with_background et_section_regular et_pb_section--absolute">
                
                
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_2_tb_header et_pb_equal_columns">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_7_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_1_tb_header">
                
                
                
                
                <a href="/#top"><span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="367" height="157" src="https://diebrillenboutique.de/wp-content/uploads/Logo_Brillen_Boutique-weiss-1.png" alt="" title="Logo_Brillen_Boutique-weiss" srcset="https://diebrillenboutique.de/wp-content/uploads/Logo_Brillen_Boutique-weiss-1.png 367w, https://diebrillenboutique.de/wp-content/uploads/Logo_Brillen_Boutique-weiss-1-300x128.png 300w" sizes="(max-width: 367px) 100vw, 367px" class="wp-image-209"></span></a>
            </div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_8_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_code et_pb_code_0_tb_header">

                    
                    
                    
            </div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3 et_pb_column_9_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
                
                
                
                
                <div id="slide-in-open" class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_4_tb_header et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light open">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p><span class="line line-1"></span><br><span class="line line-2"></span><br><span class="line line-3"></span></p></div>
            </div>
            </div>
                
                
                
                
            </div><div class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_3_tb_header slide-in-menu-container et_pb_gutters1 slide-in-menu">
                <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4 et_pb_column_10_tb_header  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_5_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner"><p>Leistungen</p></div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_6_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">Sortiment</div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">Einblicke</div>
            </div><div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_8_tb_header et_clickable  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">
                
                
                
                
                <div class="et_pb_text_inner">Kontakt</div>
            </div>
            </div>
                
                
                
                
            </div>
                
                
            </div>      </div>
    </header>
```

I'm using DIVI Builder and this: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-responsive-slide-in-menu-with-divis-theme-builder

I'm looking forward for answers!

The Burger Menu should go back to it's default state after clicking on the menu.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I deleted my answer as it was wrong. I had a look at the tutorial you are following but I'm afraid I cannot help here as I don't know anything about DIVI. Sorry, good luck.